# xml integration - post xml to a url

Tags: php, javascript, xml

please help me i am this question again

dont block this question

i want to post my xml file to a url

from where i will get a reponse xml document in return

but i dont know how to do this

i want to do this as simple as possible

without using curl or any other things

just using java script , ajx and php

please any one provide a code to do this

help.................

Comment: Ah! I just read my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943834/post-an-xml-document and didn't understand how I could've missed the javascript part. Now I believe your previous question was merged with another one although it's not strictly related, ajax->server vs php-script->server

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943834/post-an-xml-document - I've closed **that one** as the dud. PLEASE STOP posting duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery (free) its as simple as that: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/4509b4b7a43ee6bd

Hope that's help!